# What is wrong with my iptables rules so that it cannot route for openvpn?

Tags: iptables, openvpn

On contrast, `firewalld` will do the routing by simply setting up `masquerade`. So I am sure the rest of the settings are correct. Here is the general idea:

**[App -> tun0(10.0.0.2) -> Openvpn Client] ----> [Openvpn Server(10.0.0.1) -> eth0->Public IP]---->[some IP's on www]**

To implement it, here is the openvpn configuration for Client (in brief):

```
daemon
dev tun
remote 70.34.22.247
rport 1100
lport 1100
proto udp
ifconfig 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.1
writepid /run/tunpid
verb 4
route 209.51.188.116 255.255.255.255 vpn_gateway #gnu.org for debug test
```

Obviously the added routing rule on IP 209.51.188.116/32 ensures it will automatically ask the openvpn server (at 10.0.0.1) to route the request for it. `curl 209.51.188.116` would test if the openvpn does the work. I have confirmed that with this openvpn tunnel on, it stuck, but without tunnel, it worked. I have also found logging on openvpn server site so the traffic inside the tunnel did happen. Although 'tcpdump' did not show the traffic `conntrack -E` did show the traffic. Below is the configuration for server, which has log level 7 so that any packet inside the tunnel would be recorded:

```
dev tun0
lport 1100
proto udp
ifconfig 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2
verb 7
```

The routing function of CentOS 7 is clearly on:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

And for iptables, I use the iptables service, which means it would automatically load the settings using `systemctl restart iptables`, and the loading is successful otherwise an error would occur and `systemctl status iptables` would show a bad status. Here is the configuration on `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Jun  9 14:12:50 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [27:1704]  
:INPUT ACCEPT [12:648]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:216]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [3:216]
#-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j SNAT --to-source 70.34.22.247
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jun  9 14:12:50 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Jun  9 14:12:50 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [160:19179]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 1100 -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

I doubt if the `-j MASQUERADE` did not work, so I change it to directly SNAT to the address of eth0. But it would not work either. Of course, on contrast, if I disable `iptables`, and use `firwalld` instead, and set accept `1100/udp`, and `add-masquerade` everything works. So the problem must lie in the above configuration.

Do you know what is wrong with the configuration of iptables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like forwards are allowed in one direction but not in the other.
I suggest to use interfaces name instead of IP address.

Example:

```
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```